# what is the sum of this?$\frac12+ \frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16 +\dots\frac{1}{2012}+\frac{1}{2013} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the sum of $$\frac12+ \frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\frac16 +\dots\frac{1}{2012}+\frac{1}{2013} $$

Comment: This is essentially what is called a *harmonic number*, and there are no closed forms for it (although there are good approximations)

Comment: Your number is $1$ less than the [Harmonic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_{2013}$. The linked article explains how to approximate this using the logarithm, and gives better approximations.

Comment: A closed expression is $\displaystyle{\large H_{n} = \Psi\left(n + 1\right) + \gamma}$. See $\displaystyle{\large\bf\mbox{6.3.2}}$ in
[this table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not really an interesting question, I fear ...

The exact answer is $\frac{A}{B}$, where $A$ is the 873-digit number

$$\begin{align}
&1457823020375738882085285521838680376351317016179578495942597370\\
&0378320415510098781465535340716404121275266248327296358362232678\\
&6278734102622894043296263865840984434831046940807020935913518007\\
&6610170430184975025171489501039855136340044946766172114345187347\\
&2525258101947297211093973306792764671036527339494431750637074683\\
&4230708772438305435131071598225161542024364751281758482910493532\\
&5272679486529134147964088721658417270988342669017294670746222437\\
&5396289282709392060556292768642859506675716675390362111468228302\\
&0782368060066857220428567636667351228472222194509213532517098318\\
&4215312313922564589890501941681764939250636021442764267189354097\\
&6967312781103861891868999835897977944251765509632397992463764707\\
&2757539640418390812471213879592790834646976169124993489059261606\\
&2602876187541263449739774491663332258026609790766133246441424484\\
&757471204138450579265132408964711222835023\\
\end{align}$$

and $B$ is the 872-digit number

$$\begin{align}
&2029024882178588859070537995606394892063138617868032497494729352\\
&4603117588071109954985856100075037278586690682862226370908784076\\
&1373758182460385685570815580907584983469652245087586518224049939\\
&8538189200052467764823885503628456029563567766917663813400872806\\
&6581413837126629349013539786812278235204246553266267204666411453\\
&3233291465507116087957721742791662582248630820924043188884944781\\
&6407535614283438262641159101052916955096435138537168813836363531\\
&9456214006726533268868764071437503549723903396960519957683391782\\
&6358829094665518541761643350701837468138883360957730534259985433\\
&0461170299850901340867381633962516193737332035551187788058506648\\
&9862570396408121482924662574281092579439686439440266363727224229\\
&3000091507088457965475315993866302318289137980710843830365091268\\
&4178987345171765323904440193241153257507552225072663118382054707\\
&65887615406383472808692605376427780480000\\
\end{align}$$

Also, the first digits are 7.184845455 ...

Comment: +1 for the stamina . You have a mistake in the 568-th digit of the second number...Just kidding (perhaps), but how would you prove me wrong?

Comment: it's easy to prove , just write a simple python code which will give you the same answer

Comment: @Mostafa36a2 sorry, but this will just instigate flame wars about computer-assisted proofs.

Comment: [Borwein’s Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral).

Answer (score 5):

For sufficiently large $N$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} = \log{N} + \gamma + \frac{1}{2 N}+O\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\right)$$

Plugin $N=2013$ and subtract 1.  Note that $\gamma  \approx 0.577216$.  This approximation for this value of $N$ is good to about 3 significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

$$
H_{2013} - 1 = \left[\Psi\left(2014\right) + \gamma\right] - 1 = \Psi\left(2014\right) + \left(\gamma - 1\right) \approx {\tt 7.1848}\
$$